# Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed while deleting rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete every odd row in a worksheet at once but it returns the above error

Code:

```
For icount = endRow To 3 Step -2
    strDelete = strDelete & "," & icount & ":" & icount
Next icount

strDelete = Right(strDelete, Len(strDelete) - 1)
Range(strDelete).Delete shift:=xlUp        '<-- Error
```

This is what `strDelete` contains

> 7565:7565,7563:7563,7561:7561,7559:7559,7557:7557,7555:7555,7553:7553,7551:7551,7549:7549,7547:7547,7545:7545,7543:7543,
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> ,29:29,27:27,25:25,23:23,21:21,19:19,17:17,15:15,13:13,11:11,9:9,7:7,5:5,3:3

Are there any limitations to number of rows we can delete at once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've been avoiding `Union()` approach since it's time consuming

Or may be you've been not

Anyhow it *is* time consuming and when you have such a great amount of rows to delete you *must* use the `Range` approach

As already pointed out, the limit is on the length of the string to be passed to `Range()` method, which seems must be limited to some 250 characters (may be 256...)

So let's use the Range approach feeding properly shortened strings

```
For icount = endRow To 3 Step -2
    strDelete = strDelete & "," & icount & ":" & icount
Next icount

DeleteAddress Right(strDelete, Len(strDelete) - 1)

Sub DeleteAddress(ByVal address As String)
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim iArr As Long
    Dim partialAddress As String

    arr = Split(address, ",")
    iArr = LBound(arr)
    Do While iArr < UBound(arr)
        partialAddress = ""
        Do While Len(partialAddress & arr(iArr)) + 1 <= 250 And iArr < UBound(arr)
            partialAddress = partialAddress & arr(iArr) & ","
            iArr = iArr + 1
        Loop
        If Len(partialAddress & arr(iArr)) <= 250 Then
            partialAddress = partialAddress & arr(iArr)
            iArr = iArr + 1
        Else
            partialAddress = Left(partialAddress, Len(partialAddress) - 1)
        End If
        Range(partialAddress).Delete shift:=xlUp
    Loop
End Sub
```

which is much much much faster than the `Union()` approach with 7k plus rows

Comment: Yes Union is time consuming I will try this. Thanks

Comment: isn't there a faster approach ? like Rows(strDelete).Entirerow.Delete ?

Comment: I've seen you made a new post for the "fastest" thing. Check that post my answer 2nd solution! As for this post, close it: either by choosing an answer or give answerers the reason why their answers didn't solve it

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a limit to the amount of rows that can be deleted, but there is a limit to the number of characters that the `.Address` property of a `Range` can return (or in this case pass through its indexer). Instead of building a string, build an actual range with `Union`:

```
Dim toDelete As Range
For i = endRow To 3 Step -2
    If toDelete Is Nothing Then
        Set toDelete = Rows(i)
    Else
        Set toDelete = Union(toDelete, Rows(i))
    End If
Next
toDelete.Delete shift:=xlUp
```