# Delete method of range class failed after filtering table

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete all the visible rows in the table after autofilter but it is giving me that error. I tried looking up at various places since this question is asked before but I couldn't find any solution till now here's the code

```
Set rng = wk.Range(wk.Range("A1"), wk.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
        Set tbl = wk.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)

        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=16
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="=NR", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
```

> This line results in error : `wk.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & frow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`

```
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=16
```

I also tried this sub replacing the errored line but it gave me same error when deleting the rows

```
'Call RemoveVisibleRows(wk)
```

> This is the subroutine for the same

```
Sub RemoveVisibleRows(wDel As Worksheet)

Dim oRow As Range, Drng As Range
Dim myRows As Range

With wDel
    Set myRows = Intersect(.Range("A:A").EntireRow, .UsedRange)
    If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
End With

For Each oRow In myRows.Columns(1).Cells
    If Not oRow.EntireRow.Hidden And oRow.Row <> 1 Then
        If Drng Is Nothing Then
            Set Drng = oRow
        Else
            Set Drng = Union(Drng, oRow)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

> Error Line : `If Not Drng Is Nothing Then Drng.EntireRow.Delete`

```
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
On Error Resume Next
Set Target = wk.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not Target Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Rows > 1 Then
        Target.Offset(1).Resize(Target.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Should it be `if Target.Rows.Count > 1` ?

Comment: Also I am not sure why `Target.Rows.Count = 1` but clearly there are way more than 1 visible rows.

Comment: This line `Set Target = wk.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns  `$A$1:$AB$1,$A$11:$AB$11,$A$16:$AB$16,$A$23:$AB$48,$A$53:$AB$54,....................` but `Target.Rows.Count = 1`

Comment: This is a generic pattern that I develop and use. `Range().Delete may fail` if have a complex range with many non-contigous rows of data.  You may want to try my solution to [Faster way to delete rows 40k+ rows at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809939/faster-way-to-delete-rows-40k-rows-at-once/39810096#39810096).  It is a magnitude faster than deleting a large number of rows.